# PyCharm wrong unused import

Tags: python, pyqt, pycharm

Consider this code:

from AutomaticHacker import constants

```
if constants.QT5:
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, pyqtSignal, QModelIndex, Qt, QAbstractItemModel, QSize
    from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QFont
else:
    from PyQt4.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, pyqtSignal, QModelIndex, Qt, QAbstractItemModel, QSize
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor, QFont
```

or see here: [Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/xrsntrsvz/)

PyCharm marks the whole line

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QAbstractTableModel, pyqtSignal, QModelIndex, Qt, QAbstractItemModel, QSize
```

as unused import, although only QSize is not used. I know, I could simply remove QSize from import list. However, when optimizing imports automatically it would break my files.

Any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't repro on Pycharm 4.0.6 Pro, it properly drops just the unused imports leaving the rest intact.

Assuming it's a version difference, I see 2 options:

- you could re-write the import line as multiple one-import-per-line lines
- you could drop the automatic optimize imports and do it manually instead, using **Code -> Inspect Code** and the grey'd out + underlined editor highligthing of the unused imports - this is my preference since I'm pretty paranoid with the code inspections anyways.

Another point against the import optimizer: it may determine based on your current setup conditions that one side of the if can not happen and happily wipe the other half - effectively voiding the whole purpose of the selective import. Always double-check the optimizer actions!